# Implement async socket recvmsg for RX and TX timestamping in Rust

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, rust, timestamp, udp

## Objective

This project is a test for using AsyncFd (from tokio) to wrap a socket file descriptor.

## Code example

Socket file:

```rust
use nix::{
    cmsg_space,
    sys::{
        socket::{ControlMessageOwned, MsgFlags, SockaddrIn},
        time::TimeSpec,
    },
};
use tokio::io::unix::{AsyncFd, TryIoError};

use std::{
    io::{IoSlice, IoSliceMut},
    marker::PhantomData,
    os::unix::prelude::{AsRawFd, RawFd},
};

pub struct AsyncSocket<'a, T: 'a> {
    inner: AsyncFd<RawFd>,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>,
}

impl<'a, T> AsyncSocket<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(fd: RawFd) -> tokio::io::Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            // inner: AsyncFd::new(fd)?,
            inner: AsyncFd::new(fd)?,
            phantom: PhantomData,
        })
    }

    pub async fn write_to(
        &'a self,
        buffer: &'a [IoSlice<'_>; 1],
        socket_address: &SockaddrIn,
    ) -> Result<usize, TryIoError> {
        let mut guard = self.inner.writable().await.unwrap();
        let flags = MsgFlags::empty();
        let cmsgs = &mut [];
        match guard.try_io(|inner| {
            match nix::sys::socket::sendmsg(
                inner.as_raw_fd(),
                buffer,
                cmsgs,
                flags,
                Some(socket_address),
            ) {
                Ok(read_bytes) => Ok(read_bytes),
                Err(would_block) => Err(std::io::Error::from_raw_os_error(would_block as i32)),
            }
        }) {
            Ok(res) => match res {
                Ok(read_bytes) => Ok(read_bytes),
                Err(e) => {
                    eprintln!("Error {}", e);
                    Ok(0)
                }
            },
            Err(e) => Err(e),
        }
    }

    pub async fn read(
        &'a self,
        buffer: &'a mut [IoSliceMut<'_>; 1],
        flags: MsgFlags,
    ) -> Result<usize, TryIoError> {
        buffer[0].fill(0);
        let mut guard = self.inner.readable().await.unwrap();

        match guard.try_io(|inner| {
            let sys_time = nix::time::clock_gettime(nix::time::ClockId::CLOCK_REALTIME).unwrap();
            println!("Real clock {:?}", sys_time);
            println!("FLAG = {:?}", flags);
            match nix::sys::socket::recvmsg::<()>(
                inner.as_raw_fd(),
                buffer,
                Some(&mut cmsg_space!(
                    nix::sys::socket::MsgFlags,
                    nix::sys::socket::TimestampingFlag,
                    nix::sys::socket::SockFlag
                )),
                flags,
            ) {
                Ok(result) => {
                    let mut ts = TimeSpec::new(0, 0);
                    let mut _thw = TimeSpec::new(0, 0);
                    let control_messages: Vec<ControlMessageOwned> = result.cmsgs().collect();

                    println!("Control message length = {}", control_messages.len());
                    for c in control_messages {
                        match c {
                            ControlMessageOwned::ScmTimestampsns(timestamps) => {
                                _thw = timestamps.hw_raw;
                                ts = timestamps.system;
                                println!("Timestamps {:?}", timestamps);
                            }
                            ControlMessageOwned::ScmRights(_) => println!("ScmRights"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::ScmCredentials(_) => println!("ScmCredentials"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::ScmTimestamp(_) => println!("ScmTimestamp"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::ScmTimestampns(_) => println!("ScmTimestampns"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::Ipv4PacketInfo(_) => println!("Ipv4PacketInfo"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::Ipv6PacketInfo(_) => println!("Ipv6PacketInfo"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::Ipv4OrigDstAddr(_) => println!("Ipv4OrigDstAddr"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::Ipv6OrigDstAddr(_) => println!("Ipv6OrigDstAddr"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::UdpGroSegments(_) => println!("UdpGroSegments"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::RxqOvfl(_) => println!("RxqOvfl"),
                            ControlMessageOwned::Ipv4RecvErr(a, b) => {
                                println!("Received ipv4 Err {:?} from {:?}", a, b);
                            }
                            ControlMessageOwned::Ipv6RecvErr(_, _) => println!("Ipv6RecvErr"),
                            _ => println!("Other"),
                        }
                    }

                    let soft_diff = diff_systime(ts, sys_time);

                    // let hw_diff = diff_systime(thw, sys_time);

                    if soft_diff != sys_time {
                        let delta = std::time::Duration::from(soft_diff).as_micros();
                        println!("Soft Delta is {}", delta);
                    }
                    // } else if hw_diff != sys_time {
                    // //     let delta = std::time::Duration::from(hw_diff).as_micros();
                    // //     println!("Hard Delta is {}", delta);
                    // // }

                    return Ok(result.bytes);
                }
                Err(errno) => {
                    match errno {
                        nix::errno::Errno::EAGAIN => println!("EAGAIN Error"),
                        _ => println!("Other error {:?}", errno),
                    }
                    let error = std::io::Error::from_raw_os_error(errno as i32);
                    Err(error)
                }
            }
        }) {
            Ok(res) => match res {
                Ok(read_bytes) => Ok(read_bytes),
                Err(_e) => {
                    println!("Error from socket {:?}", std::io::Error::last_os_error());
                    Ok(0)
                }
            },
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Guard error {:?}", std::io::Error::last_os_error());
                Err(e)
            }
        }
        // }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> AsRawFd for AsyncSocket<'a, T> {
    fn as_raw_fd(&self) -> RawFd {
        self.inner.as_raw_fd()
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Drop for AsyncSocket<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        let fd = self.inner.as_raw_fd();
        unsafe { nix::libc::close(fd) };
    }
}

fn diff_systime(first: TimeSpec, second: TimeSpec) -> TimeSpec {
    if second > first {
        second - first
    } else {
        first - second
    }
}
```

Error.rs

```rust
#[derive(thiserror::Error, Debug)]
pub enum LibError {
    AddrParseError(#[from] std::net::AddrParseError),
    #[error(transparent)]
    IO(#[from] std::io::Error),
    OSError(#[from] nix::Error),
}

impl std::fmt::Display for LibError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", &self)
    }
}
```

Main.rs:

```rust
use std::{
    io::{IoSlice, IoSliceMut},
    str::FromStr,
    sync::{
        atomic::{AtomicU8, Ordering},
        Arc,
    },
    time::Duration,
};
mod error;
mod socket;

use nix::sys::socket::{
    bind, setsockopt,
    sockopt::{self},
    AddressFamily, MsgFlags, SockFlag, SockProtocol, SockType, SockaddrIn, TimestampingFlag,
};
use socket::AsyncSocket;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let local_sock_addr = SockaddrIn::from_str("0.0.0.0:6790").unwrap();
    let local_sock_addr1 = SockaddrIn::from_str("192.168.1.84:44581").unwrap();

    let send_sock_addr = SockaddrIn::from_str("192.168.1.123:6790").unwrap();

    let rsock = nix::sys::socket::socket(
        AddressFamily::Inet,
        SockType::Datagram,
        SockFlag::all(),
        SockProtocol::Udp,
    )?;

    let ssock = nix::sys::socket::socket(
        AddressFamily::Inet,
        SockType::Datagram,
        SockFlag::all(),
        SockProtocol::Udp,
    )?;

    // let sock_txtime = sock_txtime {
    //     clockid: nix::time::ClockId::CLOCK_MONOTONIC.as_raw(),
    //     flags: SOF_TXTIME_REPORT_ERRORS,
    // };
    setsockopt(rsock, sockopt::Timestamping, &TimestampingFlag::all())?;
    setsockopt(ssock, sockopt::Timestamping, &TimestampingFlag::all())?;
    // setsockopt(ssock, sockopt::ReuseAddr, &true)?;
    // setsockopt(rsock, sockopt::ReuseAddr, &true)?;

    // setsockopt(ssock, sockopt::TxTime, &sock_txtime)?;
    bind(ssock, &local_sock_addr1)?;
    bind(rsock, &local_sock_addr)?;

    let recv_socket: AsyncSocket<i32> = AsyncSocket::new(rsock)?;
    let send_socket: AsyncSocket<i32> = AsyncSocket::new(ssock)?;
    let atomic_i = Arc::new(AtomicU8::new(1));

    let mut read_buf = [0u8; 1024];
    let mut iov2 = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut read_buf)];

    // let mut rbuf1 = [0u8; 1024];
    let mut rbuf2 = [0u8; 1024];
    // let mut iov3 = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut rbuf1)];
    let mut iov4 = [IoSliceMut::new(&mut rbuf2)];

    loop {
        tokio::select! {
            read = recv_socket.read(&mut iov2, MsgFlags::empty()) => {
                match read {
                    Ok(v) => {
                        println!("Recv sock Received {} bytes in mes {:?}", v, iov2[0].iter().take(v).collect::<Vec<&u8>>());
                        let i = atomic_i.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
                        let sbuf: Vec<u8> = (1u8..=i).map(|el| el).collect();

                        let iov1 = [IoSlice::new(&mut sbuf.as_slice())];
                        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(15)).await;

                        let _ = recv_socket.write_to(&iov1, &local_sock_addr1).await;

                    },
                    Err(e) => println!("Recv Err {:?}", e),
                }
            },
            _tick = tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)) => {
                // println!("Tick");
                let i = atomic_i.load(Ordering::Relaxed);
                if i == 3 {
                    continue;
                    // In case you want the sending to last forever

                    // atomic_i
                    //     .fetch_update(Ordering::Relaxed, Ordering::Relaxed, |n| Some(n - n))
                    //     .unwrap();
                    // break;
                }
                let sbuf: Vec<u8> = (1u8..=i).map(|el| el).collect();
                let iov1 = [IoSlice::new(&mut sbuf.as_slice())];
                let _ = send_socket.write_to(&iov1, &send_sock_addr).await;
                // Calling read here results in a deadlock
                println!("Message {} sent", i);
                atomic_i.fetch_add(1, Ordering::Relaxed);
            },
            read2 = send_socket.read(&mut iov4, MsgFlags::empty()) => {
                match read2 {
                                Ok(v) => {
                                    println!("Send sock Received {} bytes in mes {:?}", v, iov4[0].iter().take(v).collect::<Vec<&u8>>());
                                    // This second read call is done to retrieve any messages present in the Error queue (timestamps are there)
                                    // match send_socket.read(&mut iov3, MsgFlags::MSG_ERRQUEUE).await {
                                    //     Ok(v) => println!("Send sock Received from Error queue {} bytes in mes {:?}", v, iov3[0].iter().take(v).collect::<Vec<&u8>>()),
                                    //     Err(e) => println!("Send Err {:?}", e),
                                    // }
                                 },
                                Err(e) => println!("Send Err {:?}", e),
                            }
            },
            // Adding this entry results in very inconsistent behavior for receiving Tx timestamps
            // read1 = send_socket.read(&mut iov3, MsgFlags::MSG_ERRQUEUE) => {
            //     match read1 {
                                // Ok(v) => println!("Send sock Received from Error queue {} bytes in mes {:?}", v, iov3[0].iter().take(v).collect::<Vec<&u8>>()),
                                // Err(e) => println!("Send Err {:?}", e),
            //                 }
            // },

        }
        println!("\n")
    }

    // Ok(())
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```ini
[package]
name = "socket-timestamp-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
bytes = "1.3.0"
futures = "0.3.25"
log = "0.4.17"
mio = { version = "0.8.5", features = ["os-ext"] }
nix = { version = "0.26.1", features = ["socket"] }
num_enum = "0.5.7"
thiserror = "1.0.37"
tokio = { version = "1.2", features = [
    "sync",
    "net",
    "macros",
    "rt-multi-thread",
    "time",
] }
```

## Motivation

The motivation is to be able to access configuration that is not present in common user network libraries (such as tokio, std, socket2, smoltcp, etc), such as retrieving timestamp messages for RX and TX packets.
These values can be retrieved with a call to libc's `recvmsg` in a correctly configured socket (configured with SOF timestamping flags).
Tx timestamps can be retrieved from the Socket Error Queue, by accessing the socket's control messages.

## Current problems

Tx timestamps are stored (when MSG_ERRQUEUE is used) in the error queue, but polling of the socket only happens when a message is received buffer. This results in the following behavior:

Socket 1 sends message
Timestamping stuff is queued
... no polling is triggered and the message is not retrieved

Socket 1 receives the response
If recvmsg is called with MSG_ERRQUEUE:

- Socket is polled until all timestamps from the sent messages are received

If recvmsg is called without MSG_ERRQUEUE:

- Socket is polled and receives the payload of the response, but no data from error queue is read (which is the expected behavior)

If two calls to recvmsg are placed in the select! closure, it results in inconsistent behavior where sometimes you get error queued messages but sometimes you don't. This means that a second another call to recvmsg is required to receive the remaining Tx timestamps.

## Intended overall behavior

If socket is configured to generate TX timestamps, and the Error queue has received such information, the async runtime should automatically poll the results.
When data comes in the normal recv buffer, the async runtime should also poll these results.

## Possible solutions

One way to fix it would be to poll the socket with recvmsg(...MSG_ERRQUEUE) after sending the packet. But this is cumbersome and due to scheduling, the recvmsg call can't be done immediately after the send. Ideally I would like polling to happen when there is a message in the recv buffer and when there is no message in the recv buffer, but there is a queued entry in the Error queue.
Another solution would be to place a recvmsg with MSG_ERRQUEUE right after the recvmsg (without MSG_ERRQUE). The problem here is that if the socket has not received anything, we won't poll the error queue as well.

## Request for comments

I would like help in figuring out how to retrieve TX timestamps without having to manually call recvmsg (...MSG_ERRQUEUE) to get it.

I'm open to suggestions on different approaches to the problem, i.e., without tokio AsyncFd.